# Select from DB where VALUES NOT EQUALS = array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

im doing something where users has a local database and when he clicks to checks new books, it get all the IDS(fixed) form his local database and create String separeted by comma (1,2,3,4,5) and then do a GET to my server

```
www.myserver.com/getNews?ids=1,2,4,10
```

and in the server side i do this:

1) Get the last ID(fixed) and set in a var called `$total`
2) get the IDS send by the user and create a array using .explode(",")
3) get the missing values `$missing = array_diff(range(1,$total),$ids);`
get max id and get the missing numbers between the `$total` and `$ids`

and here come the part that i think its heavy:

for each `$missing` value i do a select and build a array to display as json

```
    foreach($missing as $m) {

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE id='$m'";
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {


$emparray[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    }
}
    echo json_encode($emparray);
```

this is the only one approach or is there any other more light function?

Comment: This is commonly known as [n + 1 query problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu going to read thank you man (Valeu ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this way. Implode your array with comma then use `NOT IN` condition in your query to select all books you want.

```
$strMissing = implode(',', $missing);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE id NOT IN (".$strMissing.")";
```

Comment: jesus thats just perfect!! You know the tool very nice, reduced 60lines to just almost 10.  Worked perfectly! the only thing i had to change was the $missing to the $ids (var of ids that the user already has in his Database), $missing  can be removed from my code

thank you